# Color Stuff Inside Braces in a Desired Way With a Trigger

Tags: syntax-highlighting, regular-expression, highlight

Suppose I have `\frac{stuff}{matter}` somewhere in a file I am editing. And I want to change `stuff` and `matter`. So at the trigger of a command, I'd like to see the following take place:

`stuff` gets highlighted in red (say) and `matter` gets highlighted in blue.

This will help me keep track of whether I am editing away at `stuff` or `matter`.

Then, of course, I'd like to trigger a command which disables the highlights.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: I don't understand your question. But at the very basic level, it seems that you want to highlight codes inside braces, but with different colors rather than one. **That** is possible, though I myself don't know how to do it. I say because of rainbow parenthesis in vim for lisp programs.

Comment: Yeah I just need to color things inside braces which follow a certain phrase, like `frac`. Can you please elaborate on rainbow parentheses?

Answer (score 2):

You're basically talking about syntax highlighting, a relatively deep topic. In simplest terms, you define syntax matches through patterns and link those matches to highlight groups which define text color.

Just about everything you need to know is in `:h syntax`. You might want to start with a gentler introduction, though. This is one (though perhaps not ideal...I just have it handy): [Basic Syntax Highlighting](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/45.html)

I'll admit that I'm not that well versed in this stuff (I keep meaning to spend the time needed to learn it!) And, unfortunately, yours is not a trivial case because you have different highlighting on the same line. That being said here's my crack at it...

```
syntax region rFrac start="\frac" end="$" contains=rStuff,rMatter keepend
syntax region rStuff start="{stuff" end="}" contains=rMatter contained keepend
syntax region rMatter start="{matter" end="}" contained
" arbitrarily chosen highlight groups...Error is usually red. :)
highlight link rStuff Error
highlight link rMatter Keyword
```

*Note: I am taking your example literally. If you actually meant "stuff" to be a substitute for arbitrary text then modify the pattern(s) (i.e. the start value) to fit whatever you have in mind.*

Just run these through the command line to test it out. Works for me...mostly. :) It's possible there may be "false positives"...that is, coloring text that should not be colored. (But don't worry...if there's a superior solution someone will post it soon.)

Now once you get this working we can get into some commands to quickly turn it on or off. That's not a problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, I intended for `stuff` to be arbitrary things.

Comment: You could try `start="{[^}]*"` in rStuff, for starters.

Comment: Thanks. Let me squander an unconscionable amount of time on it to get this right. :)

Comment: Hehe. Sure. Good luck. I poke my head in a fair amount if you get stuck on something. (Though, to repeat, I'm not an expert on this stuff!)

Comment: This might be a stupid question. I copied this in my vimrc. The highlights are not taking effect. Is there a trigger command hidden in your code?

Comment: Try `:syntax enable`...though I'm surprised you don't have that already. Does syntax highlighting work for standard file types (e.g. open source code for some common language...is it colored?) Does it make a difference if you just run my commands directly on command line of a vim window?

Comment: I tried `:syntax enable`. It switched off the highlights I already had! I also tried running the command on the command line but that didn't work either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77384/discussion-between-b-layer-and-caffeinemachine).